# Rewrite $5^{12x-17}=125$ as a logarithm. Then apply the change of base formula to solve for x using the common log. Round to the nearest thousandth.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I attempted the question in the title:

> Rewrite $5^{12x-17}=125$ as a logarithm. Then apply the change of base formula to solve for x using the common log. Round to the nearest thousandth.

I arrived at $x=\frac{14}{12}$ whereas my textbook says the solution is actually this:

[image]

My working:

$$5^{12x-17}=125$$
$$\log_5(125)=12x-17$$
$$\frac{\ln(125)}{\ln(5)}=12x-17$$
$$3=12x-17$$
$$12x=14$$
$$x=\frac{14}{12}$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $\frac{5}{3}$?

Comment: Wait, how can you go from $3=12x-17$ to $12x=14$? (Yes, an arithmetic error.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your 4th step, you said $3 = 12x - 17$ then in your 5th step, you said $12x = 14,$ when it's actually $12x = 17 + 3 = 20.$ So, $x = \boxed{\frac{5}{3}}$

Comment: This is why we lay out all of our steps I guess! I just assumed my error was further up. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: @DougFir no problem :) also nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, from $5^{12x-17} = 5^3$ you can directly conclude that $12x-17 = 3 \implies x = \frac{5}{3}$ as the exponential function $a^x$ is injective (one-to-one). It is injective as its inverse exists, being the function $\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$, which you can find by making $x$ the subject in $y = a^x$.

Note that this does not hold in general. For instance, $x^2 = 4 \implies x = 2, -2$ as when drawing the line $y = 4$, it intersects the curve at two points, hence two solutions. Since $12x-17$ can be any real number, you need this property of $1$ y-value $\implies$ $1$ x-value to hold for all real $x$.

Comment: Very good answer and very good intuition ! $(+1)$

Answer (score 2):

$$3=12x-17$$
$$12x=20$$
$$x=\frac {20} {12}$$